# Can one delete a specific document in Elastic Search using Python

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I know that each document in my database has a unique '_id'. Is it possible to delete a specific document using its _id attribute? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve that using the [`delete` method](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#elasticsearch.Elasticsearch.delete)

```
es.delete(index = "my_index", doc_type = "my_type", id = "1234")
```